# Kinect Studio hogging up all memory during playback

Tags: c#, c++, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I did some data collection using Kinect Studio and I developed my own application to extract RGB and Depth data from the recorded .XEF file.

So the problem that I am having is that Kinect Studio is eating up all my RAM and thus my application cannot run properly and I cannot save RGB data (images) and the depth data...

My computer has an 8GB memory and I don't think I can get one which is more than that.

Is there any other way to extract that data smoothly? I do not really care in having 30fps recorded to the hard drive 8-10fps is fine.

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing at the moment to extract the data which seems to take so much of your hardware? Or is it just simply running the software that eats up all your RAM? This is unclear.

Comment: @KevinAvignon thanks for the quick reply... I am basically just running my own C++ developed stream saver and Kinect studio and that is about it. I used process explorer to know what is going on and turns out that Kinectservice is writing about 300MB/s of data when Kinect studio is running. I dunno what is being written and where its being written